# What is the DDD way to make sure that there is only one obj created with 2 attribute combinations

Tags: java, spring, domain-driven-design

im pretty new to the whole DDD concept and i have the following question:

Lets say i have a UI where Users can save cars by putting in a id and a name. What is the DDD way to make sure that every unique id and name combination is only created once. The cars are all Entities and will be stored in a database. Usually i would just have put a primary and a foriegn key in a DB and just check if the combination is already there and if not create/store the obj and if there is the same combination then don´t.

Now i´m thinking if this is domain logic or just a simple CRUD. If it is domain logic and if i udnerstood correctly i should make my car object decide if it is valid or not. If thats the case how would i do that?

thanks in advance!

edit:

another thing: What if every created object should be deleted after 10 days. That would be a concept in the domain and would hence be also part of the domain logic. But how should the Object know when to delete itself and how should it do it? Would that be a domain service that checks the creation date of the objects and if it is older than 10 days it should perform a delete operation inside the DB?

Answer (score 0):

I would go with a UNIQUE constraints on the 2 fields if you don't care about the validity of the values entered. That way even if someone, for some reasons, inserts/updates the records directly in the DB, the DB will prevent it.

If you care about the validity of the combined values entered, then you will have to add on top of that some logic in your code before saving it in the DB.

About your deletion mechanism, you can have a scheduler that check every day what are the data older than 10 days by checking a previously filled DB column (eg CREATED_ON) and delete them.

Comment: thanks for the reply! I do care of the validity. So that would mean i would implement some functions that check the validity and once this is checked I would store them in the UNIQUE field, right? That would mean that the logic that makes sure that there is no object which has the same Attributes (i could model the attributes as a Value Object too) happens at the DB and not in my Core-Domain, right? Same for the deltion, it happens in/on the DB (infrastructure layer) and not at my core right?

Comment: exactly? You let the DB work for you to check the uniqueness. But you have no choice, if you care about the validity of the combination, to check in a function this validity.

Answer (score 0):

"It depends".

If `id` and `name` are immutable properties that are assigned at the beginning of the objects lifetime, then the straight forward thing to do is incorporate them into the key that you use to look up the aggregate.

```
car = Garage.get(id, name)
```

If instead what you have is a relation that changes over time (for instance, if you have to worry about `name` being corrupted by a data entry error) then things become more complicated.

The general term for the problem you are describing is [set-validation](http://codebetter.com/gregyoung/2010/08/12/eventual-consistency-and-set-validation/).  And the riddle is this: in order to reliably verify that a set has some property, you need to know that the property doesn't change between when you check it and when you commit your own change.  In other words, you need to be able to lock the entire set.

Expressed more generally, the set is a collection of associated objects that we treat as a unit for the purpose of data changes.  And we have a name for that pattern: *aggregate*.

So "the registry of names" becomes an aggregate in its own right - something that you can load, modify, store, and so on.

In some cases, it can make sense to partition that into smaller aggregates ("the set of things named Bob") - that reduces the amount of data you need to load/store when managing the aggregate itself, but adds some complexity to the use case when you change a name.

Is this "better" than the answer of just using database constraints?  It depends on which side of the trade off you value more -- enforcing part of the domain invariant in the domain model and part of it in the data store adds complexity.  Also, when you start leaning on the data store to enforce part of the invariant, you begin to limit your choices of what data store to use.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer! That is exactly the problem that i am facing. Lets change the example from ID and Name to color and name. My Aggregate Car would now consist of a name and color. That would mean i would have to make a class for the color and a class for the name which then are value objetcs, right?   Wouldn´t that be wrong since they are just attributes of the car? If they are indeed value objects then the car itself would be the root aggregate . But  can a root aggregate be a root aggregate if it only consists of value objects? (Continue on my 2nd comment)

Comment: My understanding was the following: If i have a value Object 
CarData
{
    string color;
    string name;
}
and a Entity
Car
{
   CarData carData
}

that would mean that even if 2 Car Obejects have the same carData they could be different Car Objetcs, right? Which in my case would be wrong since the combination of the color (in my previous example it was the ID) and the name make the car object unique and identifiable. (I know it doesne make sense in real life since 2 cars could be a blue bmw of the same type but their identity is the VIN but i hope you still get my point)